# string indicies must be float or int error on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code, I do not understand why Im getting an error since I have an if statement:

```
df=sns.load_dataset('mpg')
print(df.dtypes)
pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates(df)
t_df= df[['horsepower', 'weight']]
midpoint= int(len(t_df)/2)
midpoint
for columns in t_df:
    for values in columns:
        if type(columns[values])== int or type(columns[values])== float:
            if result % 2 ==0:
                print( 'even')
            else:
                print('odd')
        else:
            print('np.nan')
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your loop to this:

```
for column_name in t_df:
    for value in column:
        if type(values) == int or type(values) == float:
            if value % 2 == 0:
                print('even')
            else:
                print('odd')
        else:
            print(np.nan)
```